# Female name starting with Samech in the Torah

Tags: names

Is there a female name beginning with the letter Samech in the Torah not the rest of Nach?

Comment: What an oddly specific question. Can you give some context to why you’d like to know this?

Comment: ^^Ditto. Anyhow, ‘Serach bat Asher’ is commonly spelled in Chazal with a *samech*, though not so in the Torah, AFAIK.

Comment: @Oliver Correct; Serach’s name is often spelled in Chazal with a Samech, but in the one place she’s named in Chumash (Bamidbar 26:46) it’s spelled with a Sin.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Sruli and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @DonielF Bereishit 46:17

Comment: @JoelK Good catch that she is mentioned a second time, but it’s still with a Sin and so doesn’t help the OP.

Comment: @DonielF Probably because there are women's names in Tanach beginning with each of the other letters. (For the record, it doesn't look like there are any that begin with samach.)

Answer (score -1):

There are none, according to the full list on WIKI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_women_in_the_Bible#S

Comment: This doesn't look like such a complete list. I don't claim to know the names of all women in the Old and New Testaments,  but at the very least, it's noticably missing Serach Bas Asher, mentioned in the comments of this question.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Isn't it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheerah? Because it's spelled with ש it appears as SHerah.

Comment: Not as far as I can see. Serach Bas Asher is mentioned (at least) twice in the Chumash (again, see the comments to the question). The Sheerah mentioned on this list is referring to someone mentioned in Divrei Hayamim (plus the list says she's a descendant of Ephraim, Serach is, at least per the simple reading, Bas Asher).

Comment: (For the record, not the downvoter, just pointing out my thoughts)